# IMPORTXML return #N/A on specific page of a NCBI website - scraping protected?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape this page https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/2597 to get the "official full name", "also known as" and some others informations to a Google Sheet using `IMPORTXML`.

For the "Official Full Name" (`e.g. glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase`), I try this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/55054", "//*[@id="summaryDl"]/dd[2]/text()")
```

gives me #N/A

So I try to change `""` by `''`, to use cells where I put URL and query, change the query in all the possible ways :D.

I notice that I can use `IMPORTHTML` (and have some information about tables inside the page) or `IMPORTRSS` but can't get the info I want. So I think the website doesn't block the scraping.

I thought it was a JS or XML problem but it doesn't seem to be that (in my opinion...maybe I missed something). I even try to use `IMPORTJSON` from someone code but can't get anything (probably too complex to use for, to be honest).

I'm really blocked here so if anyone can help...?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to scrape source code directly:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/55054"), 10000, 1)
```

and then do something like this to get "Also known as" value:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(
 {{""; ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/55054"), 500, 1)},
      {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/55054"), 500, 1); ""}},
 "select Col2 where Col1 contains'Also known as'"), "<dd>|</dd>", "")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: great ! sorry to ask that but....I don't get it ! how this is working ? I try to modify to get the Official Full name but can't find a solution lol...what the purpose of ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and REGEXPLACE ?

Comment: REGEXREPLACE is like a substitute to get rid of those HTML tags. ARRAY_CONSTRAIN is limiter coz whole source code is too big to be imported so we just import first 500 rows of code (coz there is what we need) and 1 column. yup official full name cant be scraped because is kinda missing from source code - its probably injected via JS so its not there but rest is kinda getable

Comment: "Official Full Name" can't be scraped